# Application stops after progress bar reaching 100

Tags: java, android

I built a small progress bar. When you press a button, the progress bar starts counting, from 1 to 100. 
I changed the button text to "Running" when it runs. But when I tried to change the text to "Again?" after it reached 100 (after the while loop finished), the application has suddenly stopped - every time.
Any help? Thank you in advance.

```
    package com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication;

    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextClock;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar pg;
    Button bt;
    int progressStatus = 0;
    TextView tv;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textID);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bt.setText("Running.");
                progressStatus = 0;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (progressStatus < 100) {
                            progressStatus++;
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    pg.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                    tv.setText("Progress: " + progressStatus + "/" + pg.getMax());
                                }
                            });
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        bt.setText("Again?");


                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Also this line should run on the UI Thread: `bt.setText("Again?");`

Comment: Error: "Unfortunately, My First Application has stopped.

Comment: @Blackbelt - UI Thread?

Comment: It's currently in the main thread though.

Comment: no it is not. Is running in the context of your Thread's subclass (new  Thread)

Comment: Oh I get it. Main thread is just in the "regular" onCreate function, or...? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes  here's a tutorial about threads. I recommend you to read it

Comment: I'll read it. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bt.setText("Running.");
            progressStatus = 0;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (progressStatus < 100) {
                        progressStatus++;
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                pg.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                tv.setText("Progress: " + progressStatus + "/" + pg.getMax());
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                bt.setText("Again?");
                            }
                        });


                }
            }).start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: First of all - thank you! Second - can you explain to me why is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, you started a new thread to check your progress status. The problem is, you cant change your UI from another thread except the UI thread. Handler  runs in the UI thread so by calling handler.post it runs the code in the UI thread. You already did that for your progress bar and the textview. So basically when using other threads make sure that when you change the UI run it in the UI thread. Also learn to check errors in logcat. You can usually find solutions by searching stackoverflow for errors shown in logcat. Could you vote up my answer? :)

Comment: Thank you! I understand my mistake now :) And I tried to upvote, but I don't have 15 reputation yet... But I'll upvote it as soon as I can. Thanks again!